# Set response header in resolver

Tags: laravel, laravel-lighthouse

I am trying to implement authentication in a custom resolver function but to achieve that, I must be able to set a cookie on the response.

I found the following [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/resolvers.html#complexity-function-signature) on what data is available, unfortunately, I see no way to access the response object nor the response headers. How would this be achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to keep the HTTP layer separate from the GraphQL layer. That means:

- don't deal with cookies in resolvers
- don't expect certain resolvers in HTTP middleware

In my experience, authentication work best when handled exclusively on the HTTP layer - use standard Laravel mechanisms such as guards, described in https://laravel.com/docs/authentication and tie it into your Lighthouse server through middleware such as `Nuwave\Lighthouse\Http\Middleware\AttemptAuthentication`.

Comment: Thx, probably the right way to go. Coming from ApolloServer on Node.js this is quite a difference in how to do things, but it seems the most plausible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set something in the response of the graphQL you can use [EndRequestEvent](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/events.html#endrequest).